# OSCALL byte, what is this?

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I recently started playing around with micro-controllers, and with a pc interface and it's software, when reading a program from a micro controller i got a field that said OSCALL byte and seems to give me a different value everytime, my question is, what is this byte? What does it stand for?

From the name i would guess something like OSScillator CALLibration, although both the S and L are doubled, this is what makes more sense to me...

Best Regards

Comment: On AVR there is a register (OSCCAL) with a similar name. It can be used to slightly vary (+/- 10%) the frequency of the internal RC-oscillator. AVRs use oscillators built with a single `s` though and it is calibrated with a single 'l', so it may be entirely different.

Comment: Are you referring to a specific mcu family or software?

Comment: On both the PIC & AVR it's called OSCCAL as far as I know, it sounds like a typo (or other meaning) in the software you're using. Maybe you could mention what you're using for programming?

Comment: According to this [related question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/94953/micro-controller-copy) he is using a Velleman K8076 with their software PicProg2009.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your related question says that you are using a 12F629, so I will refer to [this datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41190G.pdf) throughout.

Many modern microcontrollers have inbuilt oscillators.  These are fairly accurate but the exact frequency will vary due to the manufacturing process.  Because of this most of these microcontrollers have some way of "tuning" or calibrating the oscillator whilst it is running.

With the PIC 12F (and other similar PIC families) there is a register called `OSCCAL`.  You can read about it in section 9.2.5.1 "Calibrating the Internal Oscillator" on page 56 of the datasheet I linked above.

The datasheet says:

> A calibration instruction is programmed into the last location of program memory. This instruction is a `RETLW XX`, where the literal is the calibration value. The literal is placed in the `OSCCAL` register to set the calibration of the internal oscillator.

This value can be calculated and set by Microchip's PICKit2 and PICKit3 programmers and probably by some of the better compatible tools.

Example 9-1 on page 56 shows how this is loaded into the `OSCCAL` register, which is volatile and therefore needs to be set at each powerup.

```
BSF STATUS, RP0 ; Bank 1
CALL 3FFh       ; Get the cal value
MOVWF OSCCAL    ; Calibrate
BCF STATUS, RP0 ; Bank 0
```

This is a simple piece of code that selects the correct bank, calls the last memory location (0x3FF) and then moves the result into the `OSCCAL` register.  This explains why the last byte in a hex file disassembles to `RETLW XX`, it simply returns the calibration value.

If you want to use this value which is stored in program flash you need to include a small stub like the above code that runs each time your device undergoes a power-on reset.  Some PIC C compilers will automatically include this for you on relevant devices.

You can read some more about OSCCAL at the following links:

- http://picprojects.org.uk/projects/piccal.htm
- http://www.electronics-lab.com/projects/mcu/017/index.html
- http://melabs.com/resources/articles/osccal.htm

Comment: Note that, as hopefully explained by this answer, you should not get a different value from your programmer every time you read a device.  So long as you do not write to the device then the saved OSCCAL in the last byte cannot change.  I recommend you check your programmer.

Comment: thank you, this was very useful, and yes, i will probably try to get another programmer for testing because this one might be ruined... Thank you for this :)

Comment: @David: A given physical chip should always read the same value.  If one is programming a bunch of chips, however, and after programming each chip the programmer shows its OSCCAL value, it would be normal for a different value to be read from each chip.

Comment: Good clarification @supercat, this is what I meant.